# Swapping Element Position in Responsive Design w/ React & Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/planet-facts-cqk438?file=/src/components/FlexTest.js) of this project I am working on and while I'm happy with getting the JS part pretty much done, the Responsive Design is driving me a bit bonkers and I'm sure this is a simple solution with Flex but I cannot get it.

Currently the desktop view is correct and looks how it should, mobile and tablet however are not. In Mobile, the only issue is the image needs to be directly below the tabs but above the planet content. In Tablet, the Image is above both, which are then flexed together right below the image. I know one issue is I have a box container in FlexTest.js that holds BOTH the tabs and the content, so I was unable to use flex order for position there, but without those in the same container I was having issues getting them to position correctly in a different view.

[This](https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/planets-fact-site-gazqN8w_f) is what the design is meant to look like in case my description was really bad.

Comment: So from looking at your code, it looks like you’re setting a pixel size for your image, and then on the boxes flex, you’re defining the percentage of the page each box should take. If this is correct, then I think your page is trying to do both, it’s trying to keep your elements within a certain size and also trying to assign percentages of the maximum width it’s allowed to take. So it pushes them together.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! I think I may have worded the question poorly (and you possibly mentioned something I've done in error, my CSS is crap). It's not the sizes that I'm having an issue with in particular at the moment, it's how do I get the Image ABOVE the content and below the tabs in mobile (it's basically a flex column), where the positions are then totally different in Desktop

Comment: So you have your initial box which I think you want to take the entire screen, then inside of it you have two boxes one contains planet display and also contains another sibling box which takes 50% of the parent space, am I correct?

Comment: yeah It’s your elements overlapping each other correct?

Comment: Correct, there's the main box serving as the overall container, then 2 sub boxes: one holding the image, another holding the tabs and content. I think the problem is the tabs and content can't be in one box, as getting the image between them becomes a real pain

Comment: https://codepen.io/pboulos/pen/EpRppb I think this example will help you, it’s similar what you are trying to do with component 1 being your navbar and the other components being your body. I’m on my phone right now and  I think besides the width they don’t loose height.

Comment: Ok awesome man, I will take a look! This has been really frustrating me as the "difficult" part per say has been done, but the longer I've looked at this the more my head has spun around

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250035/discussion-between-mslee017-and-master-oogway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to give its idea in `tailwind-css`.

You need to switch the `flex-row` and `flex-col` properties to get this functionality to work in `tailwind-css`.

#### Output in mobile devices

[image]

---

#### Output in large devices

[image]

---

#### Code:

```
<div class="flex flex-col">
  <div class="bg-blue-400 text-center text-4xl">Header</div>
  <div class="flex-1 flex-col sm:flex sm:flex-row">
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center text-center">
      <img class="p-10" src="https://www.quicksprout.com/images/foggygoldengatebridge.jpg" alt="images" />
    </div>

    <div class="m-10 flex items-center justify-center border-4 border-red-400 text-3xl">Your Main content goes here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-blue-400 text-center text-4xl">Footer</div>
</div>
```

---

#### [Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/gqbraS49UW)